# Android: one-way binding make Switch OnCheckedChangeListener not working

Tags: android, data-binding

Im just curious about this case, about how one-way binding really work.

I have a Switch and 2 textviews which have colors that bind with checked status of the Switch

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:textColor="@{swLanguage.checked ? @color/term_condition_gray_1 : @color/term_condition_green_1}"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/swLanguage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:thumb="@drawable/term_condition_switch_thumb"
                android:track="@drawable/term_condition_switch_track" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:textColor="@{swLanguage.checked ? @color/term_condition_green_1 : @color/term_condition_gray_1}"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />
```

I want to do some extra actions when checked status of the Switch changed in java code. But as long as 2 textviews color bind with status of the switch in xml code, setOnCheckedChangeListener is not working.

So is it a problem of databinding feature itself or I just do not know how databinding really work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect ObservableBoolean with Two-way binding.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="activity"
            type="someActivity"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:textColor="@{activity.languageChecked ? @color/term_condition_gray_1 : @color/term_condition_green_1}"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/swLanguage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:checked="@={activity.languageChecked}"
            android:thumb="@drawable/term_condition_switch_thumb"
            android:track="@drawable/term_condition_switch_track" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:textColor="@{activity.languageChecked ? @color/term_condition_green_1 : @color/term_condition_gray_1}"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**Activity**

```
public ObservableBoolean languageChecked = new ObservableBoolean(false)
```

**How does it work?**

1. If the switch's checked state was changed, `languageChecked` variable will change.
2. If `languageChecked` variable was changed, the internal process of DataBinding will reflect changes of `languageChecked` into all binding object (in this case, Two `textview`)

You can change 'languageChecked' variable in Java code and also observe changes of that variable with `addOnPropertyChangedCallback`

**--- Edit ---**

If you don't use Two-way binding using ObservableBoolean and using `checked` property of the switch itself, DataBinding will use InverseBinding to achieve this.

When the build succeeds, You can watch written code in Binding Object. (in this case, my layout name is test_layout, so class name is TestLayoutBindingImpl since I used DataBindingV2)

```
// Inverse Binding Event Handlers
private androidx.databinding.InverseBindingListener swLanguageandroidCheckedAttrChanged = new androidx.databinding.InverseBindingListener() {
 @Override
 public void onChange() {
  synchronized(TestLayoutBindingImpl.this) {
   mDirtyFlags |= 0x2 L;
  }
  requestRebind();
 }
};

if ((dirtyFlags & 0x6 L) != 0) {

 // read swLanguage.checked
 swLanguageChecked = swLanguage.isChecked();
 if ((dirtyFlags & 0x6 L) != 0) {
  if (swLanguageChecked) {
   dirtyFlags |= 0x10 L;
   dirtyFlags |= 0x40 L;
  } else {
   dirtyFlags |= 0x8 L;
   dirtyFlags |= 0x20 L;
  }
 }


 // read swLanguage.checked ? @android:color/term_condition_gray_1 : @android:color/term_condition_green_1
 swLanguageCheckedMboundView1AndroidColorTermConditionGray1MboundView1AndroidColorTermConditionGreen1 = ((swLanguageChecked) ? (getColorFromResource(mboundView1, R.color.term_condition_gray_1)) : (getColorFromResource(mboundView1, R.color.term_condition_green_1)));
 // read swLanguage.checked ? @android:color/term_condition_green_1 : @android:color/term_condition_gray_1
 swLanguageCheckedMboundView2AndroidColorTermConditionGreen1MboundView2AndroidColorTermConditionGray1 = ((swLanguageChecked) ? (getColorFromResource(mboundView2, R.color.term_condition_green_1)) : (getColorFromResource(mboundView2, R.color.term_condition_gray_1)));
}
// batch finished
if ((dirtyFlags & 0x6 L) != 0) {
 // api target 1

 this.mboundView1.setTextColor(swLanguageCheckedMboundView1AndroidColorTermConditionGray1MboundView1AndroidColorTermConditionGreen1);
 this.mboundView2.setTextColor(swLanguageCheckedMboundView2AndroidColorTermConditionGreen1MboundView2AndroidColorTermConditionGray1);
}
if ((dirtyFlags & 0x4 L) != 0) {
 // api target 1

 androidx.databinding.adapters.CompoundButtonBindingAdapter.setListeners(this.swLanguage, (android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener) null, swLanguageandroidCheckedAttrChanged);
}
```

In last statement, they use `setListeners()` methods to register OnCheckedChangeListener() with `swLanguageandroidCheckedAttrChanged`. `swLanguageandroidCheckedAttrChanged` using InverseBindingAdapter to observe changes.

Since `setListener()` using `setOnCheckedChangeListener` methods to setting listener, you can't operate two `setOnCheckedChangeListener` in code between Binding Object and Java code.

So, if you want to use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` in your java code(activity), using ObservableBoolean and observe changes by `addOnPropertyChangedCallback`.

If you want to compare result of two solution, see [Gist](https://gist.github.com/WindSekirun/a086c77f8e7589b73d64748b2d4c919b)

Comment: This is one of many solutions for this usecase, but can we just use "checked" property of the Switch itself ? The code will be shorter and more simple, right ?

Comment: @user2558303 I edited answer why you can't use setOnCheckedChangeListener. check it out.